# Install python module for non-default version on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-module

I have different python versions installed on my ubuntu machine. The default version is 2.7.

So when I install any new python module, for example using:

`#apt-get install python-nfqueue`

it will be istalled just for the default version (2.7)

How can I install the new modules for the other versions?
Is there a way to do it using apt-get install?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should install Python libraries with the Python package installer, `pip`.

Create a virtualenv with the Python version you want to use, activate it, and do `pip install NetfilterQueue`. You'll still need to install the system dependencies (eg `libnetfilter-queue-dev` in this case) with `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still getting this error: `ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/netfilterqueue.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyString_FromStringAndSize`

Answer (score 2):

You can install pip to work with different versions of python. Here is a link to the pip read the docs page(http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html).

to install pip to the default version of python on your machine:

```
python get-pip.py
```

to install for non standard versions call python with the version you wish to install for:

```
python33 get-pip.py
```

you can then run pip for python version 3.3 by calling

```
pip33 install pythonmodule
```